# I am having problems with Node.js and NPM on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am new to Node.js and NPM. I just installed it on my computer and every time I try to use the command npm in CMD it shows me the following:
[image: Error]

Comment: The easiest thing is to uninstall and install an LTS NodeJS version.

Comment: Please don't post error message as screenshots. They won't show up in text searches (and the title isn't really helpful either). The Windows command prompt allows you to copy it's contents to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

This message on windows means that NODE_PATH is not set.

You can use next bat-file

```
@echo off
cd..
pushd %~dp0
set NODE_PATH=%cd%;%cd%\folder1;%cd%\folder2;
node %cd%\app.js
pause
```

or define in package.json section "scripts/start"

```
  "scripts" : {
    "start": "set NODE_PATH=.;./folder1;./folder2; && node app.js"
  }
```

and run app as `npm start`

Comment: where is the package.json file is located?
and if i want to use the batch way, where should i save the file and then run it from?

Comment: Both package.json and bat-file locates in project root/folder.

Comment: There is no project. I am trying to use npm itself not a specific project.

Comment: Ooh, sorry :) Verify that %Program Files%\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ containts modules. If they exists then try add this folder to variable PATH of system environment else reinstall Node.js.

Comment: I did both, and it's not working. Is there anyway else?