# cannot find module debug using node.js on windows10

Tags: node.js

I have installed node.js and npm on windows 10. I have also tested it, it worked fine. But when i try to open a file name 'node try.js'. It says:
module.js:442
throw err
cannot find module debug .. and few days back it worked absolutely fine but now it gives this error..why is that so? it was working previously but not now. I have also uninstall and again installed everything..but the issue remains the same. Can you tell me the problem why this error message is coming? i have checked it, it has debug files in the node_modules.

Comment: the content of try.js?

Comment: See answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405719/i-am-having-problems-with-node-js-and-npm-on-windows/

Comment: it works by unistalling and installing again and again 3 times. Thankyou